# Ffmpeg gets aborted in an Electron sandboxed application

Tags: javascript, macos, ffmpeg, electron, appstore-sandbox

I have an Electron app, published on the Mac AppStore, and sandboxed.

I'm trying to add a new feature that will encode/decode videos on the fly so I can stream more video formats in an Electron context.

I'm using [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) and a [static exec of ffmpeg](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/).

Everything works awesomely, I've uploaded the sandboxed app to Apple, and got rejected because ffmpeg is using by default a secure transport protocol which is using non-public API, this is what they've sent me with the rejection:

> Your app uses or references the following non-public API(s):
>
> '/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security'
>
> : SecIdentityCreate

Alright, after much investigation, it appears that I have to compile ffmpeg myself with a `--disable-securetransport` flag. Easy enough, I do it using the same config as the static build I've downloaded simply adding the new flag.

I manage to install every dependencies needed, except `libxavs`, no big deal I guess and simply remove its flag from the configure command:

```
./configure \
--cc=/usr/bin/clang \
--prefix=/opt/ffmpeg \
--extra-version=tessus \
--enable-avisynth \
--enable-fontconfig \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-libass \
--enable-libbluray \
--enable-libfreetype \
--enable-libgsm \
--enable-libmodplug \
--enable-libmp3lame \
--enable-libopencore-amrnb \
--enable-libopencore-amrwb \
--enable-libopus \
--enable-libsnappy \
--enable-libsoxr \
--enable-libspeex \
--enable-libtheora \
--enable-libvidstab \
--enable-libvo-amrwbenc \
--enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libvpx \
--enable-libwavpack \
--enable-libx264 \
--enable-libx265 \
--enable-libxvid \
--enable-libzmq \
--enable-libzvbi \
--enable-version3 \
--pkg-config-flags=--static \
--disable-securetransport \
--disable-ffplay
```

With the new ffmpeg exec, everything still works as expected. But once I'm packaging, signing and sandboxing the app, ffmpeg stops working as soon as I try to launch it throwing this error:

```
An error occurred ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGABRT Error: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGABRT
    at ChildProcess.eval (webpack:///../node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js?:180:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

I've tried to remove the `--disable-securetransport` flag, see if it could have messed with something, same result.

I've tried to compile on a Linux machine, just to see if it could help, same thing.

As soon as I'm using my custom compiled exec it doesn't work in the sandbox, but when using the static one, everything is ok (after I `xattr` it, because [it's quarantined and blocked in sandbox](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/clearing-the-quarantine-extended-attribute-from-downloaded-applications/)).

The only thing I've noticed that seems odd is that my custom compilation is only 20mo or so, when the static install I've downloaded is 43mo.

I'm really stuck with this.

Comment: Try with `--enable-static` and `--extra-ldflags=-static` added.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it. Could not use `--extra-ldflags=-static` though, always get an error about 'C Compiler test failing' and cross-compiling. Trying without.

Comment: @Mulvya It didn't work, I end up with the same result :(

Comment: What are your global CFLAGS, LDFLAGS?

Comment: I don't have any, should I? (afraid of the silly question)

Comment: What does `ldd <your-exec>` show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160438/discussion-between-yoannm-and-mulvya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally was able to compile my static ffmpeg executable.

I've found my solution thanks to [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/14722/20822).

Apparently, OSX has dynamic libraries located in `/usr/local/bin` which take precedence over everything else. So even if you try to compile your ffmpeg to be static, it won't work with these libraries on the way.

Once I've removed all those `/usr/local/bin/*.dylib` my build became fully static and worked perfectly in the sandbox.

Comment: hello, I am trying to fix this exact issue (reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474096/sandboxed-electron-app-cant-use-ffmpeg-mac-apple-store) did you delete files on your local computer before building ffmpeg locally? I am trying to find ` /usr/local/bin/*.dylib ` files but havent found any

Comment: I didn't delete the files, just moved them, ran the configure script, and put the files back.

I don't see them in `/usr/local/bin/*.dylib` either, but I see a bunch of them in `/usr/lib/*.dylib`.
Maybe they have been moved after an update, my script was 3 years ago, must have changed since.
Can you keep me updated so I can add an update to the solution?

Comment: I am trying to do this but I cannot write or copy files from the folder `/usr/lib` , something involving SIP apple security? trying to look into if i can disable this security

Comment: disabled SIP security and moved all `/usr/lib/*.dylib` files to a different folder on my desktop but this causes my terminal and finder windows to not work, cant open notes app. Will probably factory reset

Comment: Moving those libs shouldn't be longer than the duration of the compilation script. And be put back in place right after the compilation is done. What I did myself was scripted, first, the libs were moved, then the compilation, and finally, libs are put back in place. The system needs those libs.